# Devise attempting to create session record on unauthenticated login page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

As Rails 6+ now supports multiple databases, we've evaluated moving to Aurora PSQL where there are reader and writer databases. However, I'm noticing an immediate problem. Rails 6+ with multi-db support routes any GET requests to the reader/replica instance, but Devise is trying to run an INSERT from a simple GET request.

For example:

```
Started GET "/" for [obfuscated] at 2022-08-12 16:15:00 +0000
Processing by Users::SessionsController#new as HTML
  ↳ app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb:22:in `new'
  Rendering layout layouts/devise.html.erb
  Rendering devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/devise
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/devise (Duration: 7.1ms | Allocations: 1200)
  Rendered layout layouts/devise.html.erb (Duration: 7.4ms | Allocations: 1325)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 1.7ms | Allocations: 2704)


  
ActionView::Template::Error (Write query attempted while in readonly mode: INSERT INTO "sessions" ("session_id", "data", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"):
    15:         <% end %>
    16: </div>
    17: <div id="form-content-login">
    18:         <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    19:         <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email", class: "form-control", placeholder: "Email" %>
    20:         <div class="position-relative">
    21:                 <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "current-password", class: "form-control", placeholder: "Password" %>
  
app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb:18
app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb:27:in `new'
```

How is it possible to use a replica/read-only database for GET requests when Devise tries to write to the database on GET requests, which means it needs access to the writer db instance?

Is it because of Rails using ActiveRecord as the session store, or is there perhaps another way around this? I assume that many GET requests will happen post-login that Devise will write to ActiveRecord to "refresh" the session, causing problems.

Comment: Several solutions in the [devise issue about this](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/5133) - sorry for doing the "link and not answer" thing, but there are just too many different options to list.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get this resolved by simply wrapping "super" inside of the `ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: :writing)` method.

Comment: Great, good to hear.  Maybe, for others, you could write up what you did as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

For my solution, I ended up just wrapping the:

```
super
```

command in a block such as this:

```
      ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: :writing) do
        super
      end
```

This is located within my `new` method which is rendered via a GET request from the user's browser.